# Python unicodeDecodeError on parsing a JSON url

Tags: python, python-3.x, stackexchange-api

I am using python 3.4 and trying to parse what seems like valid JSON output from a url. ex: 
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow

This is what my code looks like

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen


def jsonify(url):
    response = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
    repo = json.loads(response)
    return repo 


 url = jsonify('http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow');
```

However, I get errors such as `UnicodeDecodeError utf-8 codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1; invalid start byte`

The script works with any other API, like github and so many others, but not with the stackexchange api

Comment: @DanD. I get `Invalid character in identifier` and it points to the `.` in after `headers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is compressed using `gzip`, you have to decompress it.

```
$ curl -v http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions\?order\=desc\&sort\=activity\&site\=stackoverflow
*   Trying 198.252.206.16...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.stackexchange.com (198.252.206.16) port 80 (#0)
> GET /2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.stackexchange.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Encoding: gzip
```

See the api.stackexchange [docs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/compression) for more details.

Example of decompression:

```
import gzip

def jsonify(url):
    response = urlopen(url).read()
    tmp = gzip.decompress(response).decode('utf-8')
    repo = json.loads(tmp)
    return repo
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I get `TypeError: the JSON object must be 'str' not 'bytes'`

Comment: @user7342807 Doesn't work? Which Python version are you on? It works for me on Python 3.6.

Comment: `python3 -V`  shows `3.4.5` I am execute my script via `python3 fetch_url.py`